# How to retrieve invisible elements form list on the page in Xamarin.UITest?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I have a list of 20 elements and when I use app.Query on the page, Xamarin.UITest gives me only 3 elements as only 3 elements are visible in UI.  How can I retrieve all 20 elements from the list inside of my UITest?

Comment: Can you show the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try using All() in Query(). Something like:

```
app.Query(c => c.All().Class("ListElementsClass"))
```

Where ListElementsClass is the class of the elements you want to search on the list.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.All/

Comment: I've only tried on Android, but I've never got `All()` to work for me - it only returns the *visible* elements, but duplicated. Does it actually work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list with scroll you can use the function app.ScrollUp() / app.ScrollDown()... and you can do your checks before each scroll
If you find another way, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @Mart for your valuable solution.Is there any other way to retrieve all the elements without scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a backdoor method to expose whatever information you need (in this case the total count of list items) and then call it via [Invoke](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/)